# How to return value from new work method in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a method to call mymysql method().It excecutes fine,but i am not able to return values from new work() method,because it is void type.How to return it..

My code is shown below,

```
public String method(final String par1,  final String par2) {

        final Seasonhdr seasonhdr=null;
        Session session=null;

        session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.doWork(new Work() {
              public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                 // seasonhdr=new Seasonhdr();
                CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call method(?,?) }");
                call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );             
                call.setString(2, par1);               
                call.setString(3,par2);            
                call.execute();            
                int status = call.getInt(1);
//i want to return this "status " from here to my controller class         
              }
            });
```

Pls note:I wrote this inside a method,and that method inside a class return type of class is my modelclass.

Comment: Can I ask what are you trying to pull off in your new Work method?

Comment: i am triying to give two STRING parameters and passing it to database.

Comment: I don't understand what that half written statement of your means, but it looks like you are trying to make things more complicated then they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`session.doReturningWork()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doReturningWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork%29) instead:

```
Integer result = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Integer> {
     @Override
     public Integer execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
         //...
         return call.getInt(1);        
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work **but** it is a bit of an ugly solution

```
public String method(final String par1,  final String par2) {
        final Long[] result = new Long[1];
        final Seasonhdr seasonhdr=null;
        Session session=null;

        session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        session.doWork(new Work() {
              public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                 // seasonhdr=new Seasonhdr();
                CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call method(?,?) }");
                call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );             
                call.setString(2, par1);               
                call.setString(3,par2);            
                call.execute();            
                result[0] = call.getInt(1);       
              }
            });
```

`result[0]` has the value returned by the class and you can access it